# It is known that $∠BAD =\frac{π}{3}$ and that the points $A$, $B$, $K$, $L$ lie on a common circle. Find $\angle ADB$.

Tags: geometry

Consider a parallelogram $ABCD$ and let $K$, $L$ be the midpoints of $BC$ and $CD$. It is known that $∠BAD =\frac{π}{3}$ and that the points $A$, $B$, $K$, $L$ lie on a common circle. Find $\angle ADB$.

I struggle greatly with geometry and I tried to use inscribed angles inside a circle and properties of parallelograms but I can't quite create the right picture to set up the correct assumptions.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I think I might give you some hints, otherwise.

Comment: No I haven't, still stuck but would appreciate a hint!

Comment: Ok, I will just give you a starting point for now, assuming you want to proceed using only Euclidean Geometry. Did you find the measure of $\angle ALK$? Call $I$ the intersection between $AL$ and $BD$. There are two distinct sets of similar triangles, now, in the figure. Can you find their similarity ratios?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Given the parallelogram ABCD and the midpoints L and K, we have LK || DB, AX : AB = 3:2 and  ∠ABC = 120, ∠DBC = ∠LKC = $x$, ∠LKB = 180 -$x$.

Since ABKL is cyclic, $\angle$ALK = 180 -  ∠ABC = 60 and ∠LAB = 180 - ∠LKB = $x$.

Apply the sine rule to the triangles DAB and LAX,

$$\frac {\sin\angle ADB}{\sin \angle DAB}=\frac {\sin x}{\sin 60} = \frac{AB}{DB}, \>\>\>\>\>
\frac {\sin\angle LAX}{\sin \angle ALX}=\frac {\sin x}{\sin 60} = \frac{LX}{AX} $$

Recognize DB = LX, AB = $\frac23$AX and multiply the two equations to get,

$$\frac {\sin^2 x}{\sin^2 60} = \frac23\implies \sin x = \frac1{\sqrt2}\implies x =45$$

Comment: Can someone explain to me why $m<ALK = 60^{\circ}$?

Comment: @Joshua Bonet - <ABK + <ALK = 180 because ABKL are on a circle. Also <ABK = 180 - LAB = 120

Answer (score 2):

[image: Parallelogram]

Please note that this post does not contain the answer to your question. Instead, I am giving you the sketch, which you were unable to draw to set up your assumptions. Ok, what the heck, I will give you the answer too. It is $\measuredangle ADB=\phi=45^0$. Now, it is up to you to prove it.

Comment: Hello @YNK thank you so much for the diagram, it makes the problem much easier to see how to attack it. Once I have a solution, I'll post it. Greatly, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more details on the path I proposed you. I invite you to fill in the missing details.

As in [YNK](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/587353/ynk)'s drawing, call $\measuredangle ADB=\phi$. Let $H$ on $BD$ such that $AH\perp BD$ and $I = AL \cap BD$.
[image]

1. Since $\square ABKL$ is cyclic, $\angle ALK$ and $\angle ABC$ are supplementary.
2. Use Thales Theorem and angle chasing to show that $\measuredangle ALD = \phi$.
3. Demonstrate that $\triangle AIB\sim \triangle DIL$, implying $\overline{AI} = 2\cdot \overline{IL}$.
4. Demonstrate that $\triangle ADL \sim \triangle ADI$, so that $\overline{AD}^2 = \overline{AI}\cdot\overline{AL}$.
5. By means of 3. and 4. conclude that $\sqrt 3 \cdot \overline{AI} = \sqrt 2 \cdot \overline{AD}$.
6. Recalling 1. and 2., show that condition 5. implies $\overline{AH} = \frac{\sqrt 2}2\cdot \overline{AD}$.
7. Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle ADH$ yields $AH \cong DH$, and thus $\phi = 45^\circ$.$\blacksquare$